# How to put image path in html::image() from database

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-blade

I wanna put an image path in may laravel code like this

```
{!!Html::image({{$mdata->company_logo}},'logo',['width'=>60,'height'=>55])!!}
```

but `{{$mdata->company_logo}}` gives an error to html::image. I'm sure that image path from `$mdata->company_logo` has a valid data, namely the image path, because I can see it by using dd($data->company_logo).. But why html::image can't show the image...??

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put the `{{ }}` around the `$mdata->company_logo`.
You are already inside a php block by using `{!! !!}` around `Html::image()`.

Try `{!!Html::image($mdata->company_logo,'logo',['width'=>60,'height'=>55])!!}`.

Comment: Aaaah... You are right.... That's really stupid from me by putting {{ }}...
Thanks btw @Jared...